# the FormsPrievewPackge the package did not load correctly visual studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin android - Microsoft visual studio 2017

can't view Layer Designer

the FormsPrievewPackge the package did not load correctly

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file '\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

Continue to show this error message? Yes No

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? The picture attached in your question is fuzzy.